# C++ initialize reference and assign variable together

Tags: c++

I have this section in my code where I am using an if else, and the ternary operator on the same bool condition. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
bool UseGroups //input parameter to a function.

    std::vector<std::vector<int>>& relevantGamesGroup = (useGroups) ? (objFlight.gamesGroup[dayIndex]) : (objFlight.gamesSubGroups[dayIndex]);

    if (useGroups) {
        numberOfGroups = objFlight.numberOfGroups[dayIndex];
    }
    else {
        numberOfGroups = 2 * (objFlight.numberOfGroups[dayIndex]);
    }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way you have it written.  You could have another ternary after the reference assignment, i.e.,
`numberOfGroups = (useGroups ? 2 : 1) * objFlight.numberOfGroups[dayIndex];`
but this is arguably less clear, and may be slightly less efficient, depending on how the compiler optimizes.

Comment: Is there a typo in `2 *` line? Should it use `SubGroups` there?

Comment: @CharlesSavoie `objFlight.numberOfGroups[dayIndex] * (useGroups + 1)` if you really want to be a smartass :)

Answer (score 5):

I would probably write it like this, because I find it quite clear to read:

```cpp
auto& relevantGamesGroup = useGroups
    ? objFlight.gamesGroup[dayIndex]
    : objFlight.gamesSubGroups[dayIndex];
auto numberOfGroups = useGroups
    ? objFlight.numberOfGroups[dayIndex]
    : objFlight.numberOfGroups[dayIndex] * 2;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need to use the variables `relevantGamesGroup` and `numberOfGroups` after only having checked the condition once, you could create and call a temporary lambda that you make return the necessary pair:

```
auto&& [relevantGamesGroup, numberOfGroups] =
    [&]() -> std::pair<std::vector<std::vector<int>>&, int>
{
    if (useGroups) return {objFlight.gamesGroup[dayIndex],
                           objFlight.numberOfGroups[dayIndex]};
    return {objFlight.gamesSubGroups[dayIndex],
            2 * objFlight.numberOfGroups[dayIndex]};
}();

// use relevantGamesGroup and numberOfGroups here
```

An alternative using the ternary/conditional operator instead of using a lambda:

```
auto&& [relevantGamesGroup, numberOfGroups] =
    useGroups ? std::pair<std::vector<std::vector<int>>&, int>
                    {objFlight.gamesGroup[dayIndex],
                     objFlight.numberOfGroups[dayIndex]}
              : std::pair<std::vector<std::vector<int>>&, int>
                    {objFlight.gamesSubGroups[dayIndex],
                     2 * objFlight.numberOfGroups[dayIndex]};

// use relevantGamesGroup and numberOfGroups here
```

---

If you use this kind of construct a lot, creating a helper function could simplify it:

```
#include <tuple>

template<class... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts...> ternary(bool cond, std::tuple<Ts...>&& True,
                                     std::tuple<Ts...>&& False) {
    return cond ? True : False;
}
```

You'd then supply the wanted types as template parameters and use structured bindings to extract the selected values / references just like above:

```
int main() {
    int a1 = 1, b1 = 2, c1 = 3;
    int a2 = 40, b2 = 50, c2 = 60;

    auto&&[a,b,c] = ternary<int&,int&,int&>(true, {a1,b1,c1}, {a2,b2,c2});

    std::cout << a << b << c << '\n';
    ++a; ++b; ++c; // these are references to a1, b1 and c1
    std::cout << a1 << b1 << c1 << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
123
234
```

With the types in your question, it could look like this:

```cpp
void func(bool useGroups) {
    auto&& [relevantGamesGroup, numberOfGroups] =
      ternary<std::vector<std::vector<int>>&, int>(useGroups,
        {objFlight.gamesGroup[dayIndex],     objFlight.numberOfGroups[dayIndex]},
        {objFlight.gamesSubGroups[dayIndex], 2 * objFlight.numberOfGroups[dayIndex]});

    // use relevantGamesGroup and numberOfGroups here
}
```

Comment: Sure it works that way? I'm having trouble replicate: https://godbolt.org/z/xGcjEjo3q Can you have a look?

Comment: @Jellyboy Yes, you just forgot to call the lambda: https://godbolt.org/z/qdTf8Yfsd

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether it is more "elegant", but if you insist of writing only one `if`/`else`, then either use a pointer instead of reference for `relevantGamesGroup` which can be default-initialized and assigned later, or a lambda can help:

```
auto& relevantGamesGroup = [&]()->decltype(auto){
    if (useGroups) {
        numberOfGroups = objFlight.numberOfGroups[dayIndex];
        return objFlight.gamesGroup[dayIndex];
    } else {
        numberOfGroups = 2 * (objFlight.numberOfGroups[dayIndex]);
        return objFlight.gamesSubGroups[dayIndex];
    }
}();
```

(Note that `->decltype(auto)` is important here, since the lambda will otherwise return by-value, not by-reference.)

And for completeness the clearly worse way of doing it with just one ternary operator:

```
auto& relevantGamesGroup = useGroups
    ? ((void)(numberOfGroups = objFlight.numberOfGroups[dayIndex]),
           objFlight.gamesGroup[dayIndex])
    : ((void)(numberOfGroups = 2 * (objFlight.numberOfGroups[dayIndex])), 
           objFlight.gamesSubGroups[dayIndex]);
```

(`(void)` cast optional if you are not using some very weird type for `numberOfGroups`)

Answer (score 1):

This code looks fine to me. Here's how I would rewrite it, but it's mostly a matter of style.

```cpp
bool useGroups;

// Use of auto
auto& relevantGamesGroup = useGroups ? objFlight.gamesGroup[dayIndex] : objFlight.gamesSubGroups[dayIndex];

numberOfGroups = objFlight.numberOfGroups[dayIndex];
if (useGroups) {
    numberOfGroups *= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is clean and can be fixed by Joe the Intern if needed be.

```
using GroupGames = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
GroupGames* relevantGamesGroup; 
if (useGroups) { 
    relevantGamesGroup = &objFlight.gamesGroup[dayIndex];
}
else {
    relevantGamesGroup = &objFlight.gamesSubGroups[dayIndex];
}

if (useGroups) {
    numberOfGroups = objFlight->numberOfGroups[dayIndex];
}
else {
    numberOfGroups = 2 * (objFlight->numberOfGroups[dayIndex]);
}
```

Or with the suggestion of @Ted Lyngmo below, it's even cleaner.

```
using GroupGames = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
GroupGames* relevantGamesGroup = &objFlight.gamesSubGroups[dayIndex];
int numberOfGroups = 2 * (objFlight->numberOfGroups[dayIndex]);
if (useGroups) { 
    relevantGamesGroup = &objFlight.gamesGroup[dayIndex];
    numberOfGroups = objFlight->numberOfGroups[dayIndex];
}
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo good advice, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! You could add `auto& relevantGamesGroup = *relevantGamesGroupPtr;` to get a nice reference after the `if` too.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have a personal preference not to use "auto" unless strictly necessary. I work with mission critical systems and I have been bitten more than once by folks using auto and creating the wrong variable type with bad consequences. I like to go the extra mile and specify crystal clear what every type should be.

Comment: @Jellyboy Oups :-)  Well, you could be explicit and make it `GroupGames& relevantGamesGroup = *relevantGamesGroupPtr;` instead.

Comment: @Rotem that's a petty comment without any technical relevance. You should remove it.

Comment: @Jellyboy sure, here's one with relevance. In your first block of code I can see no reason to have two separate `if` clauses. It adds nothing to readability.

Comment: @Rotem that's a much better observation that I can respect